# FOL Translation

Tags: logic

I'm learning first order logic right now and I'm stuck on a translation.

Key:

P(x) : x is a planet

M(x) : x is a moon

S(x) : x is a star

O(x,y) : x orbits around y

1. Only stars have planets orbiting around them.

My attempt:

Ax (x is a star and y orbits x -> y is a planet)

AxAy(S(x) /\ O(y,x)) -> P(y))

2. Every moon orbits around some planet.

Ax (x is a moon -> x orbits some planet y)

Ax (M(x) -> Ey (P(y) /\ O(x,y)))

Are these correct? Note A is "for all" and E is "there exists". Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SE Philosophy! Thanks for your contribution. Please take a quick moment to take the [tour](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour) or find [help](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help). You can perform [searches here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/search) or seek additional clarification at the [meta site](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/). Don't forget, when someone has answered your question, you can click on the arrow to reward the contributor and the checkmark to select what you feel is the best answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> 1. Only stars have planets orbiting around them.
>    AxAy(S(x) /\ O(y,x)) -> P(y))

1. "Only A B" means "if B then A", not "if A then B": "Only stars have planets which orbit them" translates as `if there is a planet orbiting x, then x must be a star`, which by the truth table of `->` is false exactly when something has a planet orbiting it but is not a star, but can still be true for objects which are stars but don't have orbiting planets (because "only" means that *at most* stars have such planets, not necessarily all of them). But `if x is a star, then x has an orbiting planet` makes these predictions precisely the wrong way round. So antecedent and succedent in the implication have to be switched.
2. You got the connectives the wrong way round: The statement should be `if y is a planet that orbits x, then x must be a star` (which means that planets orbit only starts) , not `if x is a star and y orbits x, then y must be a planet` (which would mean that stars have only planets as orbiting objects).

This gets you

> `all x all y ((P(y) ^ O(x,y)) -> S(x))`

3. This is correct, but a little unintuitive: Instead of moving the existence of a planet out of the implication to a universal quantification (which makes for a logically equivalent statement), keep the quantifier where the English sentence has it:

> `all x (exists y (P(y) ^ Q(x,y)) -> S(x))`
> ("For all objects, if there exists a planet which orbits it, then it must be a star.")

> 2. Every moon orbits around some planet.
>    Ax (M(x) -> Ey (P(y) /\ O(x,y)))

Correct.

Comment: Thank you for the insightful reply.